# Tomcat 5.5 installed as service but not visible in services?

Tags: tomcat

I have installed tomcat 5.5 as a service in my system, but when i open the services using services.msc from the run in window, the Tomcat 5.5 is not available there!! What may be the problem, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might sound a bit too simple, but I find myself often in that situation, to discover that I actually have it installed , but is not loaded or running at the moment. Other times, having a load of services in some systems, I don't see it in the list because in some cases is named differently (but Tomcat word is in it, somehow). Anyway, if you keep having issues, at Bitnami.org there is an [installer](http://bitnami.org/stack/tomcatstack) for Tomcat, it might make things easier.

Comment: Yea, your right about it, it is named differently in the service... Thanks....Cheers to you......:)

Comment: Yep, happened to me a bunch of times! Glad it solved it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use SC command to bring it in your service window(mentined as services.msc).
For example- Look for Tomcat.exe on you tomcat installation directory. let say the path is as-
`D:\Tomcat7\bin\tomcat7.exe`

And let say your **service name is Tomcat7** and display name of your service is **Apache Tomcat 7**

So your command would be below from your command prompt:

`sc Create Tomcat7 binPath= "D:\Tomcat7\bin\tomcat7.exe" DisplayName= "Apache Tomcat 7"`

On successful execution of the above command go to service window, refresh it, Now you should be seeing the Tomcat service.